# Word 2013's search pane

Tags: microsoft-word

In my Word 2013 (which I constantly use and rely on everyday) has a tendency to sometimes disable the Navigation Pane for no reason, this is starting to get frustrating, as the enablement settings just do not stick (I make the change by ticking the Navigation Pane on the View tab). Does anyone know of a possible fix and to show it permanently?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may be affected by some add-ins of word, you can try opening Word in safe mode to see if it helps: [Open Office apps in safe mode on a Windows PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72)

If it doesn't help, try repairing Office: [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).